# Error Handling with files in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling

Error Handling with files in PHP

```
$path = '/home/test/files/test.csv';
fopen($path, 'w')
```

Here I want add an error handling by throwing exceptions, on 'No file or directory is found'  and  'No permission to create a file'.

I am using Zend Framework.

By using **fopen** with **write** mode, I can create a file. But how to handle it when corresponding folder is not there?
i.e if `files` folder is not present in root structure.

How to throw an exception when no permission is permitted for creating a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should get you started.

```
function createFile($filePath)
{
  $basePath = dirname($filePath);
  if (!is_dir($basePath)) {
    throw new Exception($basePath.' is an existing directory');
  }
  if (!is_writeable($filePath) {
    throw new Exception('can not write file to '.$filePath);
  }
  touch($filePath);
}
```

Then to call

```
try {
  createFile('path/to/file.csv');
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you take a look at this link: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filesystem.asp
especially the methods `file_exists` and `is_writable`

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
try
{
  $path = '/home/test/files/test.csv';
  fopen($path, 'w')
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
  echo $e;
}
```

PHP will `echo` *whatever error* would arise there.

---

Though you can also use `is_dir` or `is_writable` functions to see if folder exists and has permission respectively:

```
is_dir(dirname($path)) or die('folder doesnt exist');
is_writable(dirname($path)) or die('folder doesnt have write permission set');
// your rest of the code here now...
```

Comment: `fopen()` doesn't throw exceptions; it produces errors. So the try/catch won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

> But how to handle it when corresponding folder is not there?

When a folder does not exist .. try to create it!

```
$dir = dirname($file);
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    if (false === @mkdir($dir, 0777, true)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Unable to create the %s directory', $dir));
    }
} elseif (!is_writable($dir)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Unable to write in the %s directory', $dir));
}

// ... using file_put_contents!
```